# HTML Text Link for iPhone to send SMS to multiple numbers

Tags: ios, html, sms, message

I can't figure out how to create an HTML link that will allow the dumping of multiple numbers into the Message app. I have tried separating by commas and semicolons without any luck. Please let me know if this is even possible, as I could not find anything about sending a text to multiple numbers on Apple's URL Scheme Reference page.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<a href="sms:/open?addresses=12345678901,98765432109">Two Numbers, no message</a>
```

it should do the trick for iOS.

Comment: Can anyone explain how this works and or provide some documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's documentation on [forming text links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH7-SW1) for iOS states that it will only accept single phone numbers, with no additional parameters (even though competitors support ?body= in the same fashion as a mailto: link works with ?subject=foo&message=bar). It would seem this also applies the same to anything more than one number, each of [my tests in JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/edm00se/Lct7D/) yielded only the first number, and no number at all with a message specified. I recommend you adjust your development to either proceed through each message you wish to send, in sequence, or adjust for just the one available recipient.

```
<!-- works fine -->  
<a href="sms:12345678901">Single Number, no message</a>
<br />
<!-- works for first number only -->
<a href="sms:12345678901,98765432109">Two Numbers, no message</a>
<br />
<!-- doesn't work at all -->
<a href="sms:12345678901?body=hello">Single Number, with message</a>
<br />
<!-- doesn't work at all -->
<a href="sms:12345678901,98765432109?body=hello">Two Numbers, with message</a>
```

Comment: If anything, it seems less supported from a web context.

Comment: It supports body at least, with & instead of ?